# Организация структуры программы с большим числом параметров в args

Tags: c#, .net, консоль

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно организовать структуры консольного приложения с большим числом параметров в args. Так же некоторые из этих параметров могут 
комбинироваться друг с другом, а некоторые не.

Где можно почитать что нибудь по этому поводу.

Comment: проблема с тем, как распарсить параметры или как их потом анализировать?

Comment: http://commandline.codeplex.com/

Comment: @KoVadim: думаю, и с тем, и с другим.